# Ignoring whitespace in ANTLRworks

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I have the following ANTLR grammar:

```
grammar mygrammar;

ASSIGNMENT 
    :   ID '=' INT
    ;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Only the ASSIGNMENT rule is actually mine, the rest are defaults added by ANTLRWorks 1.4.3.

When I come to try the grammar in the interpreter, strings such as "a=5" succeed, but strings such as "b[space]=[space]6" fail: I get a MismatchedTokenException because of the spaces:

[image: Picture of the interface with a MismatchedTokenException]

From reading the ANTLR website, and the

```
Ignore rules: WS
```

and

```
{$channel=HIDDEN}
```

text/grammar rule, it seems the whitespace should be ignored, however this is not the case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Specifying "assignment" instead of "ASSIGNMENT" fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you already found the answer, but let me explain *why* changing `ASSIGNMENT` to `assignment` solved it.

Because rules that start with a capital, are lexer rules (i.e. tokens). And `{skip();}` or `{$channel=HIDDEN;}` cause lexer rules to be skipped (or hidden) from parser rules, not from lexer rules.

That is why `ASSIGNMENT` (lexer rule) didn't accept any white spaces, and `assignment` (parser rule) does ignore them.